# Why am I getting undefined in this script

Tags: javascript

Trying to output the date plus 30 days.  I've loaded the script today and it says for the day, 'Undefined', the rest of the script is ok. 'Undefined, April 7, 2013'.

Here is my script:

```
// handle the due date
var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var monthNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December");    
var todayPlus30 = new Date();
todayPlus30.setDate(todayPlus30.getDate()+30)
var dateStr = (dayNames[todayPlus30.getDate()] + ", " + monthNames[todayPlus30.getMonth()] + " " +  todayPlus30.getDate()  + ", " +  todayPlus30.getFullYear());

$('#date').html(dateStr);
```

Comment: `todayPlus30.getDate()` gives you an integer, not a month name.

Comment: Why have I been given a -1. Deary me, you guys are harsh.  I'm new to Javascript.

Comment: @varnie Why was it working yesterday and not today?

Comment: Because in that time `todayPlus30.getDate()+30` gave you "correct" index for which there's an item in your `dayNames` array, say 6, not 7. Give it a try: `alert(dayNames[6]); alert(dayNames[7]);` and you'll see what's going on;)

Comment: @varnie Thanks for the explanation Varnie. Now I'm -2. lol Happy days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dayNames array has 7 elements, so it has elements from dayNames[0] .. dayNames[6].

When you're referencing it here:

```
dayNames[todayPlus30.getDate()]
```

you're trying to access dayNames[7] which is undefined. That's because todayPlus30.getDate() returns 7 ([getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) "returns the day of the month" (according to MDN).

Change it to:

```
dayNames[todayPlus30.getDay()]
```

to get the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

For the (integer) day of the week, you want `getDay`, not `getDate`.